# make whole image a link in dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I have made some images into links by putting the web address onto the link field in Dreamweaver, which should be really straight forward... It looks like this in the code

```
<div id="fb"> 
     <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
          <img src="graphics/social graphics/facebook.gif" width="31" height="31" alt="Facebook Logo" />
     </a>
</div>
```

But when I preview in browser the whole image does not turn into a link, only the bottom part of it does. So when I hover my mouse over the image, only at the very bottom of the image it turns into a hand. Any ideas on why this is happening would be much appreciated! Thank you!

```
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
}


body {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:800px;
  padding-top:10px;

}



#imagerow #studioimage4 {
    float: left;
}
#main #imagerow div a #Todo1 {
    float: left;
}
#social div {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
#container #main #mainimage #rotxt a #studioimage4 {
    float: left;
}

#container {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-align: left;
    color: #663300;
    width: 800px;
}
#container #main #imgcontainer #social #tripadvisor {
    width: 80px;
}
#footer #social #email .st_email_large {
}
#footer #social #email {
}
#container #main #imgcontainer #social {
    padding-top: 165px;
}
#nav-menu {
    padding-right: 65px;
    padding-left: 65px;
}
#main p {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
#googlemap {
    margin-bottom: -15px;
}
#reservations {
    margin-top: -2em;
    margin-bottom: -2em;
}
#main img {
    float: right;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
#container #main h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
}
#header {
    background: url(graphics/header.jpg) no-repeat;
    height: 148px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
#navbanner {
    height: 38px;
    background: #f09911;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#nav-menu ul
{
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#nav-menu li
{
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
#nav-menu li a
{
    line-height: 2.3em;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    color: #663300;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
#nav-menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #FFF;
        height: 38px;



}
#nav-menu li a.current {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #FFF;
        height: 38px;

}

#container #main #imgcontainer #social .a2a_kit.a2a_default_style .a2a_dd {
    color: #663300;
}

#imagerow {
    clear: both;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    width: 800px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#movers-row {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin: -120px 0 0 120px;
    ;
}
#movers-row div {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
#movers-row div img {
        float: right;
}
#studiomovers-row {
    overflow:auto
}
#studiomovers-row div {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
#studiomovers-row img {
    float: right;
}


#social {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 70px;

}
#container #main #imagerow a #Image6 {
    float: left;
}
#social div {
    width: 138px;
}
#social #fb {
    width: 107px;
}
#social #email {
    width: 40px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
#mainimage img {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
#container #main #rotxt {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
#social div p a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #663300;
}

#social div img {
    float: left;
    padding-right:8px;
    clear: right;
}

#container #main ul li {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
#contactbanner {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
#main ul {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
#main a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #9848AD;
}
#telnos {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
#main h1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
}
#main #paleohori {
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 378px;
    margin-top: 155px;
    padding-left: 250px;
}
#footer {
    background: url(graphics/footer.jpg) no-repeat;
    height: 242px;
    margin-top: -130px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
} 
#social div p {
    color: #663300;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    position: relative;
}

#social #etxt {
    color: #663300;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 2px;


}
#social #twt {
    width: 105px;
}
#social a img {
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

My CSS that I am using for the whole site is here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X3hWX)

Comment: when i edited your code i saw a missing `</div>` it might pertain to your issue

Comment: What styles are applied to this code?  Please show the CSS.  I'm guessing a float in there somewhere?

Comment: This in itself looks okay. The reason for this must be elsewhere in the layout or the CSS

Comment: Have you applied any styles to the link to give it a fixed height? The link appears on the link and not the image, so if you've given the link any specific styles limiting height or position, it's going to affect behavior

Comment: Thank you for the comments, here is the CSS I am using for the whole site, I hope this is helpful in determining what the problem is http://jsfiddle.net/X3hWX/

Answer (score 0):

make sure the `<div id="fb">` doesn't have a style applied that is cropping the content (such as an overflow hidden and a smaller height).